# onsen ui: persist dynamically added content

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a sliding-menu with two items page1 and page2:

```
<body ng-controller="PageController" >
<ons-sliding-menu main-page="page1.html"
                  menu-page="menu.html"
                  side="left"
                  max-slide-distance="250px"
                  var="menu">
</ons-sliding-menu>
<ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page >
        <ons-toolbar >
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center lang" >Page 1</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <div class="template-content" >

        </div>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
<ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button onclick="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Page 2</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <div class="template-content">

        </div>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
<ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', { closeMenu: true })">
            Page 1
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('page2.html', { closeMenu: true })">
            Page 2
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
</ons-template>
```

When I append dynamic content via jQuery ondeviceready event:

```
 $('.template-content').append('<p>Hello World</p>');
```

I will see the content at first time but when I change the view to page2 and then again to page1 the content I dynamically added is vanished. I think everytime the view changes onsen ui will destroy the dom.

How can I prevent onsen ui to destroy the dom ? 
So that my dynamically content will be persisted.

I found the "persistent" attribute but this doesn't work in my case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you use `setMainPage()`, the old page is destroyed in order to load the new one, so when you go back to the old page everything is created again. You would need to store the content of you page using something like Local Storage, for example, and create your pages loading the content from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set The Content every time you push a page. You can use the callback option like this.

```
menu.setMainPage('page1.html', { closeMenu: true, 
                                callback:function(){
                                $('.template-content').append('<p>Hello World</p>');}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the navigation logic of Onsen Ui following this guide:

http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html

You have to handle the stack navigation between the pages using the methods pushPage and popPage of navigator object.

The method setMainPage() destroys the previous page that you have created before.